# OneStepCheckout - Add new step where I can add more products to Cart

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout, quote, onestepcheckout

I'm adding a new step in OneStepCheckout page, after Billing and before Payment, where the user can see and choose other special products just once.

But the problem is that I'm not able to add those to the cart.

In `/app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php` I'm adding

```
public function saveAddons($data){


    if ($this->getQuote()->hasProductId(113)) {
         $this->getQuote()->removeItem(113);
    }

    if ($data['newProduct'] == 1) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(113);
        $params = array(
            'product' => 113,
            'qty' => 1
        );

        $this->getQuote()->addProduct($product, $params);
    }

    $this->getQuote()->save();

    $this->getCheckout()
    ->setStepData('addons', 'allow', true)
    ->setStepData('addons', 'complete', true)
    ->setStepData('payment', 'allow', true);

    return array();
}
```

There's something wrong on that piece of code. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the product to the quote, I needed to add a quoteItem with that product:

```
$quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->setProduct($product)->setQty(1);
$quoteItem->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
$quote->addItem($quoteItem);
```